# How to solve OctoberCMS database missing?

Tags: mysql, database, deployment, backend, octobercms

I ve just recently discovered OctoberCMS. Everything works perfectly on my localhost server. Once i deploy to production server i get the following error:

"Database missing

A database is required to access the back-end. Check the database is configured and migrated before trying again."

I have tried installing from cPanel and have also tried ftp and making sure the .env reflects my production database details, but still getting same error.

Can anyone here plz help? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: did you also uploaded your database on production server

Comment: Yes. In fact when you install it via cPanel you fill in the database username and pwd, etc. And the MySql database is created for u. But even with this option im still getting this error.

Comment: Did you check to make sure that the config/database.php file is actually looking at the .env file by using the env() function in its configuration options?

Comment: Let me correct what i said earlier:The database, username, password details in config/database.php file are pretty much generated for me during cPanel installation. After which the database with all necessary tables would have been generated as well. But trying to get to the backend gives this Database Missing error message.
There is no .env file as one would expect with normal Laravel app. So Im really not sure about the env() file LukeTowers is referring to. But thanks guys for your efforts nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

You should check all database accesses in `config/database.php` file. If the access is correct, try reading the configuration cache with `php artisan config:clear`.
If this does not help, and the error does not change, it is worth checking the availability of the library responsible for connecting to the base in your `php.ini` file. In my case, the problem was exactly there (the library was closed)

Answer (score 0):

I had that error after fresh install...After restarting the php server, the error was gone